# Clarification on a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

In a .Net WinForms application that I am supporting there is the following regular expression:

```
public static String MacroTemplate = @"(~#([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]*)(?::(.*))?#~)";
```

I understand most of it, so I get that it matches a string that starts with ~# and ends with #~ and then has components separated by colons. What I don't understand is the last part of the expression, specifically this part:

```
(?::(.*))?
```

Can anyone explain what this part of the expression matches? Does the last question mark indicate that this part is optional? What does ?:: mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the last question mark indicates that that part is optional. The leading `?:` makes it a non-capturing group (the group won’t be included in the resulting list of groups and can’t be used in backreferences and such); the second colon is just a colon.

So it optionally matches a colon, followed by any number of anything. It would make the last section optional and could also match any number of sections.

Comment: Thanks, minitech. It makes sense now. Non-capturing group was the concept that was unfamiliar to me.